# Postnikov tower for rationalizations of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For a nice topological space $X$, let $X_\mathbb{Q}$ denote the rationalization of $X$.  I am reading along in Hatcher's notes on spectral sequences and I have a question that is presumably very simple, but I am a total noob with these things.  Using the Serre spectral sequence for cohomology, Hatcher proves that we have a fibration $K(\mathbb{Q}, 4k-1) \to S_\mathbb{Q}^{2k} \to K(\mathbb{Q}, 2k)$.

Hatcher then claims that we can see from the existence of this fibration what the Postnikov tower for $S_\mathbb{Q}^{2k}$ must look like.  I can see that the first $2k-1$ terms of the Postnikov tower are points, the $2k$ term is $K(\mathbb{Q},2k)$ with the above fibration as the map for $S^{2k}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, and all the terms from the $2k$ term to the $4k-2$ term are just $K(\mathbb{Q}, 2k)$, but what is the $4k-1$ term of the Postnikov tower?  Is it just $K(\mathbb{Q}, 2k) \times K(\mathbb{Q}, 4k-1)$? This has all of the correct homotopy groups at least.

Comment: ... but clearly the wrong cohomology ring (by Kunneth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the Postnikov tower $(P_n)$ of $X$ must have, in stage $4k-1$, a fibration $K(\pi_{4k-1}(X),4k-1) \to P_{4k-1}\to P_{4k-2}$.

With $X= S^{2k}_\mathbb Q$, $P_{4k-2} = K(\mathbb Q,2k)$ as you pointed out, and so we must have a fibration $$K(\mathbb Q,4k-1) \to P_{4k-1}\to K(\mathbb Q,2k)$$.

Does that $P_{4k-1}$ now remind you of someone else, who could rightfully live in the Postnikov tower ?

Comment: Ahh - Thanks, ok yeah and I see that this is the right space since by Whitehead the map $X \to P_{4k-1}$ must be a homotopy equivalence.